# Getting error on updating 1.2.1 compose version on surface in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am using compose version `1.1.1` in my project. I am using `LocalRippleTheme` like this

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource
import androidx.compose.material.ExperimentalMaterialApi
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.ripple.LocalRippleTheme
import androidx.compose.material.ripple.rememberRipple
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalProvider
import androidx.compose.runtime.remember
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun ClickableItemContainer(
    rippleColor: Color = TealLight,
    content: @Composable (MutableInteractionSource) -> Unit,
    clickAction: () -> Unit
) {
    val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalRippleTheme provides LgcRippleTheme(rippleColor),
        content = {
            Surface(
                onClick = { clickAction() },
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                indication = rememberRipple(true),
                color = White
            ) {
                content(interactionSource)
            }
        }
    )
}
```

when I update to compose version to `1.2.1` I am getting weried error message on `Surface`

```
Using 'Surface(() -> Unit, Modifier = ..., Shape = ..., Color = ..., Color = ..., BorderStroke? = ..., Dp = ..., MutableInteractionSource = ..., Indication? = ..., Boolean = ..., String? = ..., Role? = ..., () -> Unit): Unit' is an error. This API is deprecated with the introduction a newer Surface function overload that accepts an onClick().
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to remove the `indication` attribute:

```
Surface(
    onClick = { clickAction() },
    interactionSource = interactionSource,
    color = White
) {
    content(interactionSource)
}
```

The M2 `1.2.0` [deprecated](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2006338) the clickable [`Surface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Surface(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,androidx.compose.foundation.Indication,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.String,androidx.compose.ui.semantics.Role,kotlin.Function0)) function with the introduction a newer [`Surface`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material/package-summary#Surface(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,kotlin.Boolean,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.foundation.BorderStroke,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.MutableInteractionSource,kotlin.Function0)) function that accepts an `onClick()`.

With this API you can't define the `indication` that is defined internally by the `clickable` modifier.

Comment: Then how should I use `rememberRipple` then ?

Comment: The `indication = rememberRipple()` is defined internally by the `Surface`